# Issue with Generating Stable Hexagonal Grids

Tags: python, pyglet, hexagonal-tiles

[showcase in pyglet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dBnF.png)

I have been attempting to solve a problem for a few weeks now. I want to create a hexagonal grid. Initially, I began with Pygame and now I am trying with Pyglet. Unfortunately, I have been unable to create an exact grid with either library.

In the example below, I am simply moving this grid for demonstration purposes. However, I have noticed that the shape of the hexagons is not consistent; they are constantly shifting and changing. In Pygame, the issue is even more pronounced, and I have been unable to find a solution for it.

Here is the code snippet I have been working with:

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes

window = pyglet.window.Window(1500, 1000)
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

def calc_points(size: tuple[int,int], coord: tuple[int,int]=(0,0)) -> list[tuple[float,float]]:
    b, a = size
    a, b = 1/4*a, 1/2*b
    
    x0, y0 = coord

    x1, y1 = x0+b, y0+a
    x2, y2 = x1+b, y1+a
    y3     =       y2+a
    y4     =       y3+a
    
    return [
        (x0, y1),
        (x1, y0),
        (x2, y1),
        (x2, y3),
        (x1, y4),
        (x0, y3),
        (x0, y1)
    ]

def hex_mul(size: tuple[float,float], pos: tuple[float,float]) -> tuple[float,float]:
    """given size of hexagon and position in hexagon grid, outputs real coord"""
    x, y = pos
    b, a = size
    a, b = 1/2*a, 1/2*b

    coord = (x * 2 * b + y % 2 * b,
             y * 3 / 2 * a )

    return coord

from math import sqrt

size = 20.0
border = 2.0

size = (sqrt(3)/2*size,size)
border = (sqrt(3)/2*border,border)

reduced_size = (size[0] - border[0], size[1] - border[1])

hexagons = []
p = calc_points(reduced_size)

for y in range(200):
    for x in range(200):
        coord = hex_mul(size, (x,y))
        r_coord = (coord[0] + border[0] / 2, coord[1] + border[1] / 2)

        shape = shapes.Polygon(*p, color=(180,170,160,255), batch=batch)
        shape.position = r_coord
        hexagons.append(
            shape
        )

@window.event
def on_draw():
    for s in hexagons:
        x, y = s.position
        s.position = (x+0.8, y+0.7)
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

1. Adjusting the parameters for hexagonal grid generation in both Pygame and Pyglet.
2. Experimenting with various rendering and updating techniques.

Expected Outcome:

I expected to create a stable hexagonal grid that remains consistent and does not distort or shift during movement and or persistent gaps between hexagons. However, despite my attempts, I have not been able to achieve the desired stability using either Pygame or Pyglet.

(If possible i would rather use pygame, since i have got more used to it.)

[after aplying qsrt approx in pygame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BaiT.png)

Comment: You need to be more specific. You have to decide. Either ask about Pyglet or Pygame. But don't ask both at once in one question.

Comment: Problem is almost same in both pyglet or pygame, i think the solution needs to be general.

Answer (score 0):

A likely reason for your hexagons to appear wonky is that you're using the "real" `sqrt(3)` to determine their size. That's an irrational number (or at least the closest `float` approximation to one), so each hexagon will be at a different offset relative to the pixels on the screen. You'll likely get better results you choose a rational approximation so that many of your hexagons fall on the same subpixel offsets.

Try something like this:

```
size = 20.0
border = 2.0

sqrt3_approx = 1.75  # try out different approximations to see what looks best

size = (sqrt3_approx/2*size,size)
border = (sqrt3_approx/2*border,border)
```

Comment: this seems to fix the problem partialy, so it part of a problem

Answer (score 0):

i fixed my problems by moving some point dimensions by one pixel "by hand".. this gives me a proper hexagon with pygame.draw.polygon, but i am also ashamed.

```
polytop = [[radius + radius * math.sin(2 * math.pi * i / 6), radius + radius * math.cos(2 * math.pi * i / 6)] for i in range(6)]
polytop[4][1] += 1
polytop[1][0] += 1
polytop[2][0] += 1
if radius % 2:
    polytop[2][1] += 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).